The rule of draw if the same position repeats itself 3 times
Sometimes I hear that after losing the right for castling all position are different from the ones that before losing it.
I don't think so.
Like you can move the rook back and forth and losing the right for castling, but if for example the route between the king and the rook is not empty, So, in any case the castling is not possible. So if all the pieces are in the same place, it is still the same position (if it it turn of the same player and all en passsant options are the same).
Am I right?

Also this

So your answer that I am wrong?
